# OpenID Connect - response_type=query vs form_post. Which is better?

Tags: openid-connect

Is there a defined benefit to using query vs form_post for the response_type, particularly in terms of security? My thinking is:

- query has more limits due to URL length limitations, but no reliance on JavaScript to auto-submit the form (unless there is some way to auto-submit the form_post without JavaScript? I don’t know if one).
- form_post has the higher capacity for data but requires the JavaScript auto-submit behaviour.

I am using query at present since it feels more “pure” but wondering if I’ve made the right choice.

Can’t find any resources suggesting why one is better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be recommended when tokens were returned directly in the browser response. These days it is more standard to use the [code flow](https://curity.io/resources/learn/openid-code-flow/), in which case only an authorization code is returned, which cannot be exploited due to these characteristics:

- One time use
- Short lived
- Protected by a PKCE code_verifier
- Protected by a client_secret

These days the most cutting edge option is to use [response_mode=jwt](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jarm-tutorial/), to protect against potential man in the browser attacks. The flow is illustrated in [this Curity code example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/financial-grade-oauth-agent/#openid-connect-messages) for a Single Page App.

Finally, `form_post` can have usability problems, eg if the user signs in, then hits the back button, and receives a form resubmission warning.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get user consent prompt then user: **prompt=select_account**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=WEBHOOK_URLredirect&response_mode=query&prompt=select_account&scope=YOUR_SCOPES
```